# how to display Chemical formula in Android

Tags: java, android, parsing, count, sequence

Need an idea on how we can parse a string and convert into chemical formula.

Example : 1

InputString is "CCHHNaNaOO"
Output should be C2H2Na2O2

Example 2 : 
InputString is "CCHHNaNaOOCCC"
Output should be C2H2Na2O2C3

I got how to do with single chars but have problem with doing Na[2 letters in a string]

Any idea or heads up will be helpful

Thank you!

Comment: Then, can you show how you did it with one char?

Comment: If you're iterating over the string character by character, you can detect the start of a new element by checking if the `char` is a capital letter.

Comment: I guess the quick and dirty way is to iterate the string and, for each upper-case letter, look ahead and see if the next character is lower case. If it is, take the two characters as a single name, and then advance one position. You have to be a bit careful not to run over the end of the string. You could use a Hashtable<String,Integer> to accumulate the counts for each element. Perhaps a nicer way would be to use a simple finite-state machine, with each character's upper-case or lower-case status being used to trigger the state changes. But that might be overkill here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's two parts to your problem. Firstly, you want to split out the individual elements based on if the first character is a capital letter. This can be done with `String.split()`:

```
String[] elements = s.split("(?=[A-Z])");
```

Secondly, you'll want to total up the number of common **concurrent** entries of each element in your array.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String token = null;
int counter = 1;

for (String element : elements) {
   if (!element.equals(token)) {
       if (token != null) {
           sb.append(token);
           if(counter > 1) sb.append(counter);
       }

       token = element;
       counter = 1;
   } else {
       counter++;
   }
}


// We've reached the end, add final element
sb.append(token);
if (counter > 1) sb.append(counter);
return sb.toString();
```

Comment: Dear Michael, Thank you sharing your idea. But when i split the string with capital letters i get somethng like below.

Comment: @user2792746 Like I said, that code was untested. Now I'm home from work I'll do a quick spike to see if there's a couple of things to iron out. What's the output you're getting?

Comment: Dear Michael, Thank you sharing your idea. But when i split the string with capital letters i get something like below. if this is my input HHOONaNaHHO, i get list in form of [, H, H, O, O, Na, Na, H, H, O].Now i have to count occurrences of each symbol in sequential manner.So my output should look like H2O2Na2H2O. I have tried with second part which you suggested but i don't get result in this way. Any heads up on this will be helpful.         Thank you for your time!!

Comment: Wow Michael!! It is working correctly. Thank you for your help and time.